# Counting number of threads in clojure

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, clojure

I am new to clojure and am performing multi-threading over a large dataset. I need to look at the number of threads running by the program so that I may control the processing of the file. Is there a way to get a graphical representation of the threads and sub-threads that a clojure program is running? If not a graphical representation at least the number of threads being run by the program?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind i used Thread/activeCount

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JConsole of the JVM your
program is running on, the same way you do with Java.